# How would you share a random value across many classes?

Tags: java

I want to create a random int value to be used across multiple classes. Each time I have created a new set of instances of these classes, I want a this new random int value to be used for all of these. The random value should be the same though.

So in a nutshell, I want to have a random index to be created and used across multiple classes that are working together to generate data.

Should this random value be generated on the top of the stack and called statically within each of the classes that are working together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a class containing a field with the random value. Supply a getter method to access this. Then, share an new instance of this class with each new batch of your classes.

E.g.

```
private static final Random random = new Random();
private final int randomValue = random.nextInt();

...

public int getRandomValue() {
  return randomValue;
}
```

This way, the random number is identical for each group of classes, but different for each group.

Comment: AOL case is by convention used for constants, which `Random` is not.

Comment: Awesome! This is very helpful! What if there is one class that is generating all of the new instances of the group of classes? Should I just create this same scenario within that class?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Depends on exactly how pedantically you define "constant". It's fairly common to equate it with "static final" in Java, insofar as the value of the object reference stays the same, even if the state of the object is mutable. (In C++ parlance, the difference between `* const` and `const *`.)

Comment: @millimoose "Doesn't change"?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline In the above, `RANDOM` will, for the duration of the program, point to the same instance of `Random`. That's certainly "not changing".

Comment: @millimoose The object does change. `final` does not mean constant.

Comment: @TomHawtin Good point. I tend to use it for static finals of any type, but I guess that's incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this

```
static class Utility {
    private static final int variable = (int)Math.round(1000*Math.random());

        public static int getVariable() {
            return variable;
        }
}
```

It works like Math.PI etc.
e.g.

```
System.out.println(Utility.getVariable());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it into the related objects in their constructors:

```
class Main {
    public static void main() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (...) {
            int index = rnd.nextInt();
            // one set of related instances
            Foo f = new Foo(index);
            Bar b = new Bar(index);
        }
    }
}

class Foo {
    int randomIndex;
    public Foo(int randomIndex) {
        this.randomIndex = randomIndex;
        // etc.
    }
}

class Bar { ... }
```

If you want a value to be different between instances of a class (whether they exist simultaneously or not), **don't make it static**.

Answer (score 1):

First reify the notion of "group" you're talking about by using a dedicated class that will hold metadata associated with each group :

```
class Group
{
    private int index = -1;

    public Group(int index)
    {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public int getIndex()
    {
        return index;
    }
}
```

Then assign to each class its group-info data.

If you know the index before instanciation of each object use the constructor.
Note that the **factory-pattern** could help you encapsulate the instanciation process if it is complex.

If you know it latter and still have access to the instances use a dedicated method   :

```
public void assignToGroup(Group group)
```

If you do not have access to the instances anymore you may use some simple inversion : each instance would ask for its group :

```
getMyGroup(this)
```

to an external method :

```
public Group getMyGroup(MyClass instance)
{
    // ... some complex logic to determine the right group based on the instance state ...
}
```