# Create a Single Random Value to Share Across Classes Java

Tags: java

Final(?) edit:
Leonardo Pina's solution looks like what I needed. Thank you all for your input! My code is now:

```
public final class Roll {
    private static final Random r1 = new Random();
    private final int r = level();

    private static final int level() {
        int s = 1, e = 100;
        int r = r1.nextInt((e - s) + 1) + s;
        return r;
    }

    public int itemType() {
        boolean b = r1.nextBoolean();
        int a = ((b) ? 1 : 2);
        return a;
    }

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }

}
```

And the implementation in the other class:

```
public class Damage {
    Roll r;

    Damage(Roll r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public int damageOut() {
        int a = r.getR();   //roll value
        return a * 2;   //test math on r
    }
}
```

Edit:
Thank you for the responses. However, it seems my use of this method was not clear. Apologies! This is what I need:

Call Roll class, get e.g. "12"
OtherClass1 receives "12" from Roll via getter
OtherClass2 *also* receives "12" from Roll via getter
Call Roll class again, get a *new* random number, e.g. "48"
OtherClass1 receives "48" from Roll via getter
OtherClass2 *also* receives "48" from Roll via getter

Using the solutions provided, Roll creates a single random number and never creates a new one again. I need Roll to create random numbers on demand, and then share that random number with other classes. I do not want it to only generate one number and then stop. I hope this makes sense. Thank you for the responses so far!

---

I have searched for and read the other threads of a similar topic (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177252/how-would-you-share-a-random-value-across-many-classes%20/%22this%20one%22), which is how I tried to solve my problem), but the methods I have tried have failed. I need to create a single random value and then use that same value across multiple classes.

My random class:

```
public final class Roll {
    private static final Random r1 = new Random();
    private final int r = level();

    private static final int level() {
        int s = 1, e = 100;
        int r = r1.nextInt((e - s) + 1) + s;
        return r;
    }

    public int itemType() {
        boolean b = r1.nextBoolean();
        int a = ((b) ? 1 : 2);
        return a;
    }

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }

}
```

And a class where I call for the static value from the random class:

```
public class OtherClass{
    Roll roll = new Roll();
    int r = roll.getR();

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }
}
```

When I call the getter from OtherClass, the value is different than the getter from Roll. I would expect them to be the same value.

I call the values for testing like so:

```
Roll roll = new Roll();
int r = roll.getR();
OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
int o = other.getR();
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new instance of **OtherClass** you also create a new instance of **Roll**, therefore, the rolls are different.

You need to make sure you are getting the value R from the same object Roll.

This could be achieved by using a singleton pattern for the Roll class, or you could specify the Roll object you want to use to get values, this way you could have several rolls for different purposes. i.e.

---

**Edit:**
Answering your edit: to get a new number, you should update the value of r in the Roll class whenever you generate a new value, for example, instead of returning a value, the level() method could update the r variable:

```
public final class Roll {
    private static final Random r1 = new Random();
    // We now attribute a value to r uppon construction
    private final int r;
    public Roll() {
        level();
    }

    // Whenever level() is called the value of r is updated
    private static final int level() {
        int s = 1, e = 100;
        int r = r1.nextInt((e - s) + 1) + s;
        this.r = r;
    }

    public int itemType() {
        boolean b = r1.nextBoolean();
        int a = ((b) ? 1 : 2);
        return a;
    }

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }

}
```

---

```
class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the Roll obj
        Roll myRoll = new Roll();
        // Initialize the other objs with myRoll
        Board board = new Board(myRoll);
        Player player = new Player(myRoll);
        // Do your comparison
        int b = board.getRoll();
        int p = player.getRoll();
        // EDIT: get a new value
        myRoll.level();
        // Do your comparison once more
        b = board.getRoll();
        p = player.getRoll();

    }

    class Board {
        Roll r;
        Board(Roll roll) {
            this.r = roll;
        }
        public int getRoll() {
            return r.getR();
        }
    }

    class Player {
        Roll r;
        Player(Roll roll) {
            this.r = roll;
        }
        public int getRoll() {
            return r.getR();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your method seems to be working for me. I will update the post to reflect the solution. My implementation looks a little rough, but it's a start. Thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem mate, if this answer addressed all of your concerns, please mark it as accepted, anyhow, feel free to ask further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to make it work would be to field `r` in class `Roll` as static, so that the `Roll` class looks like this:

```
ublic final class Roll {
private static final Random r1 = new Random();
private static final int r = level();

private static final int level() {
    int s = 1, e = 100;
    int r = r1.nextInt((e - s) + 1) + s;
    return r;
}

public int itemType() {
    boolean b = r1.nextBoolean();
    int a = ((b) ? 1 : 2);
    return a;
}

public int getR() {
    return r;
}
```

}

Or second approach would be to make `Roll` class a singleton.

Edit:
Since you have changed the intent of the question, and from what I understand you should look into Observer design pattern. It may be helpful for your case.

Comment: Why doesn't `getR()` instead `return level()`?

Comment: This level() method seems unnecessary. r can just be statically initialized.

Comment: @Chrisport I agree with you, I merely fixed the code which of
zingrook by adding static keyword to the r field. cricket_007 It can be done in many different ways. I just corrected his code. Feel free to suggest a better approach. Thanks

Comment: @cricket_007 Good catch. Changed.

Comment: @Chrisport Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

As someone said in the comments, you should follow the singleton design pattern, meaning that your variable `r` should be unique across all `Roll` class instances. To do this, your code will have to look something like this:

```
public class RandomTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Roll roll = new Roll();
        int r = roll.getR();

        OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
        int o = other.getR();
    }

}

class Roll {
    private static Random r1 = new Random();
    private static int r = level();

    private static final int level() {
        int s = 1, e = 100;
        int r = r1.nextInt((e - s) + 1) + s;
        return r;
    }

    public int itemType() {
        boolean b = r1.nextBoolean();
        int a = ((b) ? 1 : 2);
        return a;
    }

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }
}

class OtherClass{
    Roll roll = new Roll();
    int r = roll.getR();

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: `return r;` in `getR()` should instead be `return level()` and `return roll.getR()`, respectivly. In other words, if `r` changes, then `getR()` is never reflecting that change

Answer (score 0):

How about sharing the `Roll` instance?

```
Roll roll = new Roll();
// roll.roll(); // Unclear how you "refresh" the data

int r = roll.getR();
OtherClass other = new OtherClass(roll);
int o = other.getR();

assert(o == r);
```

---

```
class OtherClass {
    private final Roll roll;

    public OtherClass(Roll roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    public int getR() {
        return roll.getR();
    }
}
```

Tip: I think a `Dice` class with a `roll()` method makes more sense.

Comment: Actually, in the context of the app I am working on, dice makes sense for the class, and roll for the method! Thanks for the idea!